Generalizing the Subset Sum Problem to Finding Matching Subsets from Two Arrays
How can the subset sum problem, where the sum of n specific values equals a given number, be generalized to include arrays containing multiple elements?
Specifically, the subset sum problem involves selecting y numbers from x candidate numbers (where x >= 1) such that their sum equals a given number n. If we extend this problem, where n is no longer a single value but an array containing multiple numbers, how should the algorithm be designed?
In real-world, especially in the financial sector, this problem often arises in reconciliation tasks involving multiple numbers against another set of multiple numbers.
I have currently designed a piece of code to solve the subset sum problem for a specific value n. By incorporating various pruning algorithms, it can usually return results within seconds when searching for elements that sum to a specific value from around 300 elements. However, I am unable to extend this to multiple numbers.

Is it unacceptable to run your existing code multiple times?

There are a lot of corresponding values, and manually selecting them one by one is unrealistic. More importantly, users also need to consider multiple combinations of arrays.
